# Automatically subscribe to YouTube channels via Channel_ID

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to migrate subscriptions from an older youtube account to a newer one that I'll use going forward. I pulled my subscriptions export from the old one and have around 470+ subs that I'll need to migrate over.

I found this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/youtube-data-api-subscription-set-3/?ref=rp) which absolutely works with automatically subscribing to a youtube channel via their channel_id but it seems like in the key value pair I can only run the .py script once per value.

I tried all sorts of googling to see how I can include multiple values in the key (channelId) but it always only auto subs to the last one in the dictionary.

Can someone please help show me what I'm missing? I feel like there has to be a way to add multiple channelId values in there key dictionary, right?!

Here's what my code looks like > [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c991Z.png)

````py
import os
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies
# the name of a file that contains
# client_id and client_secret.
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

# This scope allows for full read/write access
# to the authenticated user's account and
# requires requests to use an SSL connection.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

def get_authenticated_service():
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def print_response(response):
    print(response)

# Build a resource based on a list of
# properties given as key-value pairs.
# Leave properties with empty values out
# of the inserted resource.
def build_resource(properties):
    resource = {}
    for p in properties:
        # Given a key like "snippet.title", split into
        # "snippet" and "title", where "snippet" will be
        # an object and "title" will be a property in that object.
        prop_array = p.split('.')
        ref = resource
        for pa in range(0, len(prop_array)):
            is_array = False
            key = prop_array[pa]

            # For properties that have array values, convert a name like
            # "snippet.tags[]" to snippet.tags, and set a flag to handle
            # the value as an array.
            if key[-2:] == '[]':
                key = key[0:len(key)-2:]
                is_array = True

            if pa == (len(prop_array) - 1):
                # Leave properties without values
                # out of inserted resource.
                if properties[p]:
                    if is_array:
                        ref[key] = properties[p].split(', ')
                    else:
                        ref[key] = properties[p]
            elif key not in ref:
                # For example, the property is "snippet.title",
                # but the resource does not yet have a "snippet"
                # object. Create the snippet object here.
                # Setting "ref = ref[key]" means that in the
                # next time through the "for pa in range ..." loop,
                # we will be setting a property in the
                # resource's "snippet" object.
                ref[key] = {}
                ref = ref[key]
            else:
                # For example, the property is "snippet.description",
                # and the resource already has a "snippet" object.
                ref = ref[key]
    return resource

# Remove keyword arguments that are not set
def remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs):
    good_kwargs = {}
    if kwargs is not None:
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if value:
                good_kwargs[key] = value
    return good_kwargs

def subscriptions_insert(client, properties, **kwargs):
    resource = build_resource(properties)
    kwargs = remove_empty_kwargs(**kwargs)

    response = client.subscriptions().insert(
        body = resource,**kwargs).execute()

    return print_response(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # When running locally, disable OAuthlib's
    # HTTPs verification. When running in production
    # * do not * leave this option enabled.
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
    client = get_authenticated_service()
    
    subscriptions_insert(client,
        {'snippet.resourceId.kind': 'youtube# channel',
             'snippet.resourceId.channelId': 'UC09fL42MpkktKZWmWxYiDhw', 'UC0Q7Hlz75NYhYAuq6O0fqHw'},
            part ='snippet')```
````

Answer (score 3):

According to [YouTube Data API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) ([Subscriptions: insert endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) and [Subscriptions resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#resource)), it seems that you can only subscribe a channel at a time. As [you have by default 10,000 of quota per day](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota), except if you request extended quota, because Subscriptions: insert costs 50 of quota, then for 470+ subscriptions, you would need 3 days to proceed.

Otherwise you can proceed as follows, it seems that the first time I tried with ~500 channels I have been subscribed to ~290 of them but now I mostly only receive (when removing `-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'` from the cURL request):

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
    ],
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
}
```

So it's an unsure method that you can try to deepen.

Ever wondered how to do that in a single request without using any quota?

Go on an ad hoc YouTube channel `YOUR_CHANNEL` that you want to subscribed to: https://www.youtube.com/channel/YOUR_CHANNEL_ID

Open the `Network` tab of your web-browser by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (on Firefox) and filter XHR requests.
Now click on `Subscribe`.

You should see a request to `subscribe`, copy it as cURL (by right-clicking).
Change at the end

```
"channelIds":["YOUR_CHANNEL_ID"]
```

to:

```
"channelIds":["YOUR_CHANNEL_ID_0, YOUR_CHANNEL_ID_1, ..., YOUR_CHANNEL_ID_499"]
```

Where `YOUR_CHANNEL_ID_0` is your `YOUR_CHANNEL_ID` and `YOUR_CHANNEL_ID_1` the second channel you want to subscribe to and so forth.

Execute the modified cURL request in a terminal and that's it!

Note that [this webpage](https://www.youtube.com/feed/library) contains a subscriptions count and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels) contains all your subscriptions.

To get more than 249 different channels, I used:

```py
import requests, json, os

channelIds = set()
pageToken = ''
API_KEY = 'AIzaSy...'

i = 0
while len(channelIds) < 250:
    url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q={i}&type=channel&maxResults=50&key={API_KEY}'
    if pageToken != '':
        url += f"&pageToken={pageToken}"
    content = requests.get(url).text
    data = json.loads(content)
    for item in data['items']:
        channelIds.add(item['id']['channelId'])
    print(len(channelIds))
    if 'nextPageToken' in data:
        pageToken = data['nextPageToken']
    else:
        break
    i += 1

print('["' + '","'.join(channelIds) + '"]', len(channelIds))

# Try with subscribing channel by channel

for channelId in channelIds:
    print(channelId)
    request = """REQUEST > /dev/null 2> /dev/null"""
    request = request.replace('CHANNEL_ID', channelId)
    os.system(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

[As @Benjamin Loison has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74778707), there is a quota on the limit on the usage of the API. If you'd like to raise the limit, I think there is a form you can fill out to request more. However, I don't recommend you do so since the form is applicable mainly for a large application that will be used for a long time and involve a long process of human inspection on what you're trying to build (This is based on my personal experience, might not be entirely accurate).

My suggestion would be to use the script you have to print out a list of channel links, and you can click into each of them and press the subscribe button. 470-ish channels should not take you a long time.